# org-reveal customization of title slide

Tags: reactjs, org-mode

I'm having trouble customizing the title slide in a react.js presentation created with org-mode and org-reveal. I've tried following the information [here](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal#set-the-title-slide) and by referring to this question on the subject [here](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/issues/115). However, I'm unable to achieve any changes. Here is my test presentation:

```
#+Title: Hello, world!
#+Author: First Last
#+Email: myemaill@server.com


#+REVEAL_ROOT: file:///Users/username/Documents/reveal.js
#+REVEAL_TITLE_SLIDE_TEMPLATE: "<h1>%s</h1>"

* H1
```

This should make the title slide only show the title. However, no amount of changes/variations I do have any effect. If I manually set `org-reveal-title-slide` to anything but its default `'auto` then I lose the title slide completely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an iteration of what I was trying that works:

`#+OPTIONS: reveal_title_slide:"<h1>%t</h1>"` with no space after the  `:`

I cannot get the alternative setting of `REVEAL_TITLE_SLIDE_TEMPLATE` to work.

Comment: me too, can't get `REVEAL_TITLE_SLIDE_TEMPLATE` to work.